# repeat html table header after n row in php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to repeat table header after n row. I want to print the results on a paper, and so if there are more than just one paper, I want this table header on the second page also.

```
    <table> 
        <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
            <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
        </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <?php if(isset($people) && is_array($people) && count($people)>0) : ?>
        <?php $rows = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($people as $person) : ?>
        <tr >
            <td class="td-center"><?php echo $rows + 1; ?></td> 
            <td class="td-center"><?php echo $person->Name; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php $rows++; ?> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I used the CSS below, but unfortunately couldn't get any results.

```
 thead{
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

how should I do that?!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are looking for

Comment: I think he is trying to create pagination with css and JS or smth like that ... he wants to write the table header again after each nth result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeat after 100 rows...

```
<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <?php if(isset($people) && is_array($people) && count($people)>0) : ?>
    <?php $rows = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($people as $person) : ?>
    <?php if($rows % 100 == 0) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
    </tr>       
    <?php } ?> 
    <tr >
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $rows + 1; ?></td> 
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $person->person_Position; ?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php $rows++; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with something like that (display every 5 rows your head line):

```
<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <?php if(isset($people) && is_array($people) && count($people)>0) : ?>
    <?php $rows = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($people as $person) : ?>
    <?php if ($rows%5==0) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
      </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
    <tr >
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $rows + 1; ?></td> 
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $person->Name; ?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php $rows++; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <?php if(isset($people) && is_array($people) && count($people)>0) : ?>
    <?php $rows = 0; ?>
    <?php $n = 10; //this can be a result form DB?>
    <?php foreach($people as $person) : ?>
    <?php if ($rows % $n == 0) { //repeat after nth row?>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Num</th> 
        <th style="width:100px">Name</th> 
      </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
    <tr >
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $rows + 1; ?></td> 
        <td class="td-center"><?php echo $person->Name; ?></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php $rows++; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

hope this helps! Although I would recommend pagination with query DB if the results are from query. In this way, you will consume a LOT less resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_chunk()` for more readable code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
<?php foreach(array_chunk($people, 10) as $chunkOfPeople) {?>
<!-- your headers here -->
  <?php foreach($chunkOfPeople as $person) {?>
    <?php //loop the properties of $person and create rows ?>
  <?php } ?> //end inner loop
<?php } ?> //end outer loop
```